# Linking Post URL to Thumbnails on Slider

Tags: php, wordpress

The below code pulls in all the thumbnails of posts in a category when you are viewing one of the posts in that category. I need to link the title of the post to the image.

```
<div id="workSlider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $workthumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),'full' );
            if( $workthumb && $currentID != $post->ID ) {

            echo '<li><a href=""><img src="'. $workthumb[0].'" ></a></li>';
            }
         ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you try it with $post->title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><img src="'. get_the_title() .'" ></a></li>';` I think this will work.

Comment: I am happy that, I have helped you .